# Clearing the definition of an environment

Tags: environments

I need to render the minipage environment ineffective (the reason is that I need to sometimes compile latex documents for a visually impaired reader with a huge point size, not compatible with the general layout of the document).

```
\renewenvironment{minipage}[1]{\relax}{\relax}
```

fails because of the optional arguments sometimes passed to \begin{minipage}

I guess I can use \renewcommand on \minipage and \endminipage to adapt their definitions from latex.ltx but I was wondering if there isn't a more straightforward way to do it.

Comment: Use the `xparse` package to make a new version of the minipage with 3 optional and one mandatory argument. Something like (untested) `\RenewDocumentEnvironment{minipage}{ o o o m }{}{}`.

Comment: I might have misunderstood. Should the contents of the minipage go away as well? Becasue `xparse` can handle that as well: just add `+b` after `m` in the argument list in my previous comment

Comment: Another option is `\usepackage{comment}\excludecoment{minipage}`

Comment: @daleif solution works just fine thanks. And no, I didn't need to clear the contents of the minipage. You should post it as an answer so that I can accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays making macros with multiple optional args is super easy using the xparse package (the contents of which will be added to the latex kernel in a near future)

Minipage takes three optional and one mandatory. So if you just want to remove the effect of Minipage leaving the contents intact use

```
 \RenewDocumentEnvironment{minipage}{ o o o m }{}{}
```